# Add localization to vue-tables2 table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-tables-2

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/matfish2/jfa5t4sm/) is a similar example of table that I have in my project.

My project is a multilingual website so I would like to have vue-table also translated to the language user currently uses. What I want to be translated is only the table elements not the actual data inside the table. For instance in the example string 'records' should be translated to the users language. Also text 'Showing 1 to 10 of 50 records' under the pagination should be translated.

[image: This should be translated].

Example code:

```
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: ['name', 'code', 'uri'],
    data: getData(),
    options: {
      headings: {
        name: 'Country Name',
        code: 'Country Code',
        uri: 'View Record'
      },
      sortable: ['name', 'code'],
      filterable: ['name', 'code']
    }
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options">
    <a slot="uri" slot-scope="props" target="_blank" :href="props.row.uri" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></a>

    <div slot="child_row" slot-scope="props">
      The link to {{props.row.name}} is <a :href="props.row.uri">{{props.row.uri}}</a>
    </div>

  </v-client-table>
</div>
```

If anyone have any clue how I should do this I would be grateful.

Comment: If you need anything else, you can lookup in the plugin repository: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2) there is the "texts" option which refers to the "texts" option within this [file](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2/blob/master/lib/config/defaults.js).

So, in your data, you can simply add the `texts` parameter and edit them:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        columns: ['name', 'code', 'uri'],
        data: getData(),
        options: {
            headings: {
                name: 'Country Name',
                code: 'Country Code',
                uri: 'View Record'
            },
            sortable: ['name', 'code'],
            filterable: ['name', 'code'],
            // EDITABLE TEXT OPTIONS:
            texts: {
                count: "Showing {from} to {to} of {count} records|{count} records|One record",
                first: 'First',
                last: 'Last',
                filter: "Filter:",
                filterPlaceholder: "Search query",
                limit: "Records:",
                page: "Page:",
                noResults: "No matching records",
                filterBy: "Filter by {column}",
                loading: 'Loading...',
                defaultOption: 'Select {column}',
                columns: 'Columns'
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a *wonderful* resource; thank you for compiling the list. This library has some of the least helpful [documentation](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/) I've ever worked with; this answer is awesome and greatly appreciated.